# How to insert unbreaking space in sed?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I need to replace all spaces in file with unbreaking spaces to prevent merging multiple spaces into one in HTML.

How I can do it with sed?

I tried `sed -e 's/ /\u00A0/g'`, but it isn`t working. It is replace spaces with "00A0" sequence, not unbreaking space

Comment: Simply inserting an unbreaking space in the replacement part should work. Do you experience otherwise?

Comment: If this is for HTML rendering, then w\hat about using CSS to control how breaks work?

Comment: Bash doesn't care at all what's inside the single quotes. If your `sed` doesn't let you put a literal non-breaking space there, show us the exact error message.

Comment: *"unbreaking space here"* is `U+00A0` in Unicode. It is `C2 A0` in UTF-8, and `A0` in ISO 8859 and codepage 1252. You should state the [encoding or presentation format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings) you desire.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this: `sed -i 's/ /\&nbsp;/g' file.html`

Comment: I need unbreaking space symbol, not HTML tag.

Comment: `&nbsp;` is that, not a html tag

Comment: Wouldn't this also replace the spaces inside tags, for instance `<a href=...>` would end up as `<a&nbsp;href=...>` -- I'm not sure if that's what OP wanted. @PHPoeniX, please clarify what you need.

Comment: @Eddinn it is HTML`s SGML construction

Comment: @Socowi I wrote what I need in question: "How I can insert unbreaking space into the command?"

Comment: It's an "entity" not a "tag". But regardless of whether you put `&nbsp;` or a literal character, you will be wrecking your HTML where it requires regular spaces syntactically.

Comment: yes, this will destroy the html file, but I just answered his question about how he could add it to `sed`